Playwright Node How to Upload Video Using API POST Request
I am struggling on the right syntax for uploading a video to POST API Request using Playwright Node. I have tried a bunch of options and I can never get a successful response. My POST expects a formData
My headers:
const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      Authorization: token,
      organizationId,
      'version': '3'
}

I've tried:
const response = await request.post('/X', {
      headers,
      data: {
        multipart: {
          file: {
            name: 'test.mp4',
            mimeType: 'video/mp4',
            buffer: fs.createReadStream('video1.mp4'),
          }
        }
      }
    });

const response = await request.post('/X', {
      headers,
      multipart: {
          file: {
            name: 'test.mp4',
            mimeType: 'video/mp4',
            buffer: fs.createReadStream('video1.mp4'),
          }
        }
    });

And got Error: apiRequestContext.post: Unexpected buffer type of 'data.file'
And:
const response = await request.post('/X', {
      headers,
      data: formData
    });

const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('video', fs.createReadStream('video1.mp4'));
    const resp = await IntegrationAPI.createFirebaseUpload({ request }, {
      token: mobileResp.token,
      organizationId: process.env.automationOrganizationId,
      formData
    });

Where video1.mp4 lives in the same location as this file
